# laravel sort collection of filenames

Tags: laravel, collections

I having trouble reading some files alphabetically as shown in the picture. Is required that they keep the order after reading them because they will generate respective records in a table later. I tried collect and sort options but unlucky. In the pc filesystem they appear in the correct order

I get an array of files with this code and then print the array with dd(), so ultimately I want to sort those filenames alphabetically.

```
$files = ((Storage::disk('public')->files("uploads")));
```

dd($files);

I tried sort collection method, also convert into array and use asort() but no luck

thanks, any help is appreciated

[image: image of dd()]

I think I got the answer with this: (I'm happy)

```
$files = ((Storage::disk('public')->files("uploads")));
sort($files, SORT_NATURAL);
```

[sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQ5Z.png)

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried achieving this with.

Comment: The order that they would appear in the operating system UI does not necessarily correlate with the order that they are stored in the file system because operating systems tend to do their own sorting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort method
eg:

```
$collection->sortKeysDesc();
```